# Neo4j 10k MERGE statements fail

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-javascript

I am running a batch merge operation in Neo4j, but it keeps on failing. I increased the heap size and heap limit but is seems like my operations is perhaps not supported or there's a more appropriate method of doing this.

I have 10k of such MERGE statements

```
var transaction = `
                   MERGE (n0: Account {sfRecordId:$Id0})
                         ON CREATE SET ...
                         ON MATCH SET ...
                   MERGE (n1: Account {sfRecordId:$Id1})
                         ON CREATE SET ...
                         ON MATCH SET ...
                   MERGE ... //10k

// then send to Neo4j via the Javascript driver:
 tx.run(transaction, bindParams)
```

My heap size is set to

```
server.memory.heap.initial_size=2G
server.memory.heap.max_size=3G
```

I have tried sending them all at once, I have tried batching them into batches of 100, 500, 1, and 10,000.

None of these seems to get my 10k to be inserted.

The first random 500-4k get in, but then the server crashes with an out of memory error.

Comment: Try putting all the data into an object, and use UNWIND to iterate through it with a single MERGE statement.

Comment: how did you put them in batches of 10k records? Thanks.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Your recommendation worked!
I submitted the entire transaction as an UNWIND and it processed in a matter of seconds.

Comment: @jose_bacoy I was submitting the transactions as a string with values bound. I changed the statement to a single UNWIND with binding to an array of 10k entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating a very large statement to bulk insert data is not recommended. A good way of inserting such bulk data is to prepare a list of objects, and use `UNWIND` to iterate through it:

```
UNWIND $data as item
MERGE (n:Account {sfRecordId:item.Id})
                    ON CREATE SET ...
                    ON MATCH SET ...
```